# unable to run express 2.5.8 on ubuntu 11 on amazon aws

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express 2.5.8 on ubuntu 11 (amazon aws).  I have connect 1.7.2 & node 0.6.15.  I am able to run node (listen on port 3000 for instance) - however, when I use express, it appears to throw the following error:

got an uncaught error: Uncaught, unspecified 'error' event

There is no other service bound on that port at that time - I have tried re-installing express 2.5.8 and connect 1.7.2 (work on local box) - any insight to troubleshoot the issue more quickly will be greatly appreciated.  Once again, the code (using express runs fine on local box - on server, I can run a non express node server on that same port (I close it down before I run the express server instance).

Thanks

Comment: Are you using any EventEmitters? This sounds like a problem with your code. If you can post it, that would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pilot error - the issue was with the redis connection pwd (I had to fix it in my code to match the pwd in the redis.conf to resolve the issue ).  Added better handling (which I should have done to begin with).

Thank you Wes for commenting - appreciated.